# Hint MVT $f(x)=f(0)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\colon[0,\infty)\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ be a function which is differentiable for $x>0$ with $|f'(x)|\leqslant1$ for $x>0$. Prove that $f(x)$ is right continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: Do you mean MVT, or MTV? I've never seen that in MTV...

Comment: MVT meaning mean value theorem

Answer (score 3):

According to the MVT, for all $x>0$ we have $$\left|f(x)-f(0)\right| =\left| f'(\xi) \right| \left| x-0 \right| $$
where $\xi$ is some point between $0$ and $x$. Using the bound on the derivative we find $$\left|f(x)-f(0) \right| \leq \left| x \right|, $$
thus it suffices to take $\delta<\varepsilon$...

Comment: after you find the last inequality, where do you go from there?

Comment: @sarah For any $\varepsilon>0$ choose $\delta=\varepsilon/2$.